# How to call model function into my controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a model folder inside the App folder named Models, in this folder I have created a UserModel, and my controller is in App/Http/Controller folder name UserController. How can I call to my UserModel into the UserController?

I have tried below code.

My Controller **UserController.php**: It is in App/Http/Controller Folder.

```
    <?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use App\Models;


class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        $users = new UserModel();
    }

    public function index(){
        $user_id = $_GET['id'];
        $token = $_GET['token'];
        $userInfo = $this->users->getUserInformation($user_id); 
        return view('profile.users')->with('user_details', $userInfo);
    }

}
```

and my Model: **UserModel.php** it is in App/Models folder.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    public function getUserInformation($id){
        return "User id is : ".$id;
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: you are including App\User but using UserModel

Comment: How did you call your user model? User or UserModel?

Comment: Did you try this `UserModel::getUserInformation($id);` ? and please `use App\Models\UserModel;`

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: Yes i have fixed, by moving Model file to App root folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did it right, just small tweak and you are good to go:
the `$users` variable in your controller must be declared correctly to be accessible to all method, so update your controller to this:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use App\Models\UserModel;


class UsersController extends Controller {
    protected $users;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->users = new UserModel();
    }

    public function index(){
        $user_id = $_GET['id'];
        $token = $_GET['token'];
        $userInfo = $this->users->getUserInformation($user_id); 
        return view('profile.users')->with('user_details', $userInfo);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

since `$this->users` is returning a collection so you will have to loop over it and then call your model function in it.

```
foreach($this->users as $user){
     $userInfo = $user->getUserInformation($user_id);
}

///
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to take advantage of Laravel's dependency injection and inject the dependency directly on the controller method:

```
class UsersController extends Controller {


    public function index(UserModel $users, Request $request){
        //Using the request object is recommended
        $user_id = $request->input('id');
        $token = $request->input('token');
        $userInfo = $users->getUserInformation($user_id); 
        return view('profile.users')->with('user_details', $userInfo);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really read documentation and make your style more Laravel-like

> Controller:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UsersController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        // this is where you show list of users
        // I recommend you reading this: 
        //https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers
    }

    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return view('profile.users.show')->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

> Route:

```
Route::get('users/{user}', 'UsersController@show');
```

> View:

```
<span>User id is : {{ $user->id }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You will do like this

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    public function getUserInformation(){
        return "User id is : ".$this->id;
    }   
}
?>
```

In controller

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\UserModel;
use App\Models;


class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $user_id = $_GET['id'];
        $token = $_GET['token'];
        $user = UserModel::find($user_id);
        $userInfo = $user->getUserInformation(); 
        return view('profile.users')->with('user_details', $userInfo);
    }

}
```

please try and let me know.